# How to update price when selecting item from select option tag

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue when I select a sub-item from the select option tag, which incremental into my price is showing.

For example, my price: is 1, I select sub-item has price is 1 then which incremental 1+1 = 2, but when I select other items also has a price is 1 then which incremental 2+1 = 3.

How to prevent incremental on my price?

Sub-item: `{name: 'name1', price: 1}` and `{name: 'name2', price: 1}`

My code:

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState(item.price)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (optionSelected === 'option') {
      setPrice(item.price)
    } else if (!isEmpty(optionSelected)) {
      setPrice(price + optionSelected.price)
    }
  }, [optionSelected])
```

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd `setPrice` should use the callback argument, since it updates price using its previous value.
(See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
setPrice((price)=>(price + optionSelected.price))
```

Comment: Sorry, this way is not to work, it is still incremental on my price.

Answer (score 0):

This is always adding:

```
setPrice(price + optionSelected.price)
```

So since the previous price was the item price plus the sub-item price, the new price will be that previous total plus the new sub-item price.

Instead of adding to the existing total price, add to the item price to produce a new total:

```
setPrice(item.price + optionSelected.price)
```